# SSH Permission denied (public key), but root ssh works

Tags: server, ssh

I'm trying to setup ssh access for a user account that I created with chef on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 12.04 server. I had the options set in DigitalOcean to automatically copy my mac's ssh key when the droplet is created.

I can ssh in as root with no issues, but my other user fails to authenticate. this seems to be a common issue, and I checked some of the other answers, and found this command to get more info:

```bsh
ssh -vvv -i id_rsa user@serverIP
```

The logs for the root user (which succeeds) with that command are

debug

```
1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/evan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp snip!
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: snip!
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

failing user:

debug

```
1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/evan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/evan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/evan/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Which to me means that the public key is incorrect. But, if I login as the root user and go to

```
home/otheraccount/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then I can see that my ssh key is there. I thought maybe there was an error, so I did:

```bsh
cp .ssh/authorized_keys ~/home/otheraccout/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But that didn't help. I don't know where else to look.

My `etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
"sshd_config" 88L, 2508C
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# GS

SAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM no
Banner /etc/ssh_banner
```

edit:

```
drwx------ 2 deploy deploy 4096 Apr 20 06:00 .ssh
-rw------- 1 deploy deploy 820 Apr 20 05:35 authorized_keys
```

Edit2:

As suggested in the comments, `/var/log/authlog` contains:

```
Apr 21 04:59:30 localhost sshd[586]: User deploy not allowed because account is locked
Apr 21 04:59:30 localhost sshd[586]: input_userauth_request: invalid user deploy [preauth]
```

I tried to do:

```bsh
sudo usermod --expiredate -1 deploy
```

It returned:

```
no changes
```

Comment: Are your permissions correct? `~/home/otheraccount/.ssh` should have `700` and `~/home/otheraccount/.ssh/authorized_keys` should have `600` permission and both the files should be owned by `otheraccount`

Comment: I think they're correct, deploy is otheraccount:   ```drwx------ 2 deploy deploy 4096 Apr 20 06:00 .ssh``` ```-rw------- 1 deploy deploy  820 Apr 20 05:35 authorized_keys```

Comment: what are the log lines in `serverIP` (`/var/log/auth.log`) when you try to login as `deploy` user?

Comment: interesting, it complains that the user is locked, I added the logs above.

Comment: won't let me edit the above comment: I fixed this with ```passwd -u```. Can ssh in as ```deploy``` now, but really curious why my chef deploy is creating locked users. Please copy/paste your comment above as an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- SSH logins can fail for various reasons(incorrect directory/file permissions,incorrect keys etc.) and the connecting client will just get `Permission denied` or `No more authentication methods to try` or some generic error.
- The exact reason for the login failure will be available in ssh log `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` depending on the syslog configuration.

Comment: This is the best answer to all questions about failing SSH logins problem I've ever seen! Instead of randomly guessing on wrong permissions and file names as all other answers suggest, just check mentioned logs and they contain all the information you need!

Comment: The exact reason is not in my log file. All it says is that the session was open than closed.

Comment: I suspect these logs are helpful if you're looking at the machine acting as server (sshd), but not if you're trying to connect to a remote machine to which you don't have access.

Comment: e.g. on server `root@# less /var/log/secure`
`sshd[23971]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /xxx/yyy/.ssh`

Comment: Great answer! My error was `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/xyz/.ssh/authorized_keys` as well. `chmod 600 /home/xyz/.ssh/authorized_keys` solved the issue. Actually, all of the .ssh folder contents should best be set to 600 (rw-------).

Answer (score 4):

Same problem for me fresh CentOS7 install.

**1. check home dir permissions** and ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys permissions (as @clement says)

```
chmod o-w ~/; chmod 700 ~/.ssh; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**2. check** /etc/ssh/**sshd_config** settings && service sshd restart (after each edit) Useful: try "LogLevel VERBOSE" in sshd_config.

**I still got password prompt after checking all that was ok.**

Run ssh client with -vvv logs:

```
debug3: send_pubkey_test 
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
```

Server (/var/log/secure) logs:

```
Failed publickey for * from * port * ssh2: RSA *
```

ssh server doesn't send more error info to client as that would be a security risk.

If I ran sshd on different port 'sshd -p 5555 -d'. The key worked. Passwordless login ok. WTF?

**SAD :-( to say I then disabled selinux (set SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config) and reboot. Passwordless login then worked ok.**

*my* current working sshd_config settings:

```
[root@hp-bl-05 ~]# grep -vE "^#|^$" /etc/ssh/sshd_config  
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel VERBOSE
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
HostbasedAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
UseDNS no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

So it would be nice to know could we change something small in selinux to get passwordless ssh login to work. Can anyone improve the answer?

same here:
https://superuser.com/questions/352368/ssh-still-asks-for-password-after-setting-up-key-based-authentication/1072999#1072999

Comment: How to disable sshd strict checking "bad ownership or modes for file"?

Comment: Well, openssh source code is available >;0). There is no way to disable that. It is strict on permissions to try and enforce a basic level of user security.